# factorial method resulting in error

Tags: c#, factorial

I'm trying to get the factorial value of number **66**, but my method resulting me an output **0**. But whenever I try to get the factorial of **5**, it is resulting me an output **120**. Could anyone please tell me why?

```
 public static int factorial(int n)
 {
            if (n == 1)
                return n;
            return n * factorial(n - 1);
 }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calculate factorials in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186357/calculate-factorials-in-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure - factorials get very big, very fast. You're overflowing the bounds of int *very* quickly... and at some point you'll have multiplied by enough factors to get an overflow to 0, which will then keep the value at 0 forever.

According to a quick Google search, 66 factorial is 5.44344939 × 10<sup>92</sup> - which is considerably more than `int` can handle, or even `long` or `decimal`. You could get `double` to handle it - you'd lose a huge amount of precision, and that would accumulate really quickly too, but at least it wouldn't overflow...

Answer (score 4):

66! does not fit into an `int`. Use `BigInteger`.

Comment: It won't nearly fit into an long either

Answer (score 4):

Your method overflows. See the following example:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine(factorial(66));
}

public static int factorial(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return n;

    var result = n * factorial(n - 1);

    Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", n, result);

    return result;
}
```

With this example, the results of each iteration is printed.

You see that at one point, result becomes `0` and this means that every iteration from that point on becomes `n * 0`.

You can try using `BigInteger`. This will give the correct result. [Calculate factorials in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186357/calculate-factorials-in-c/4186388#4186388) contains more information on this.

Comment: Bump but note BigInteger is 4.0, consider http://intx.codeplex.com/ or http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/solverfoundation for a solution for earlier versions.

Comment: The SO article also describes a `BigInteger` implementation on CodeProject: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/biginteger.aspx.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that the factorial of 66 is way to large to fit into an `int`. I think it will also we way to large to fit into a `long`.

As an example, `factorial(20)` will return `2432902008176640000`

Answer (score 2):

The factorial of 50 is 3.0414093202×1064 which exeeds already what a int can contain.

Use `long` or `BigInteger` for this.

Comment: Actually, it will easily overflow long as well.

Answer (score 1):

You get numeric overflow, 66! ~= 5e92 which is way larger than an `int` can handle. Also, factorials are better calculated using a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

Approximately 13 or 14 is the largest number whose factorial fits in an int... If you switch to long, it'll be aroung 18 or 19 if I recall correctly. If you wish arbitraty big numbers you'd have to write your own big arithmetic library or use an existing one :)

Answer (score 0):

## You need to use the appropriate data type.

In this case the Big Integer data type is probably best seeing as how fast the numbers get real big.

### Here is the way you use this data type.

[image: pic1]

Right click on your project, choose the add reference menu.

[image: pic2]

Look for the system.numerics library and add it.

[image: pic3]

You then add the using clause in your code.

[image: pic4]

And then you can initialise variable with the keyword as usual.