# Saving factorial in long integer

Tags: c#, stack-overflow, long-integer, factorial

I am using the following code to get the Factorial, but it seems to be limited for me.

```
private Int64 GetFactorial(Int64 value)
{
    if (value <= 1)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return value * GetFactorial(value - 1);
}
```

But it seems to only allow the values upto `65` on `66`th value, it provides a `0` as a result and the result is negative too if the value is 65 or near. What can I do to allow more values to work with, and get result with having the `System.StackOverflowException`?

Comment: Duplicate questions check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4202626/factorial-method-resulting-in-error?rq=1

Comment: mildly curious how you get something up to 65/66, as 65! ~= 10^90

Comment: @KevinL I was testing this out, I tried 100, it gave me error, I tried 60 it worked, so I started counting down and I got 65 as the limit.

Comment: If you were seriously interested in using factorials, I suggest that you would not be using the naïve method of recursion to calculate them. If you look at what you need the factorial for, you may be able to eliminate overflow problems.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, do you mean to say `for` loop?

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan Yes, a `for` loop. But consider if you wanted to calculate 99!/97! - you only need to calculate 99*98.

Comment: @AndrewMorton, nah it is just a simple 99! calculator, :) division and other are not involved here. and yes, I would change the logic here. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to check out the BigInteger struct, as it allows integers of an arbitrarily-large size: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Uint64 will get you more, not sure how many though.

Comment: Didn't expect much, but thought it might be a bit more. I trust your math more than mine!

Comment: actually less, since uint64 is what, double the size? and with the value being in the range of (supposedly) 60s, it'd overflow just as fast... (i was thinking fibbonaci numbers)

Comment: Yep - big integer looks better +1