# Why does computing factorial of relatively small numbers (34+) return 0?

Tags: c#, console-application

```cs
int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int factorial = 1;
    
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
    factorial *= i;    
}
Console.WriteLine(factorial);
```

This code runs in Console Application, but when a number is above 34 the application returns 0.

Why is 0 returned and what can be done to compute factorial of large numbers?

Answer (score 6):

You're going out of range of what the variable can store.  That's effectively a factorial, which grows faster than the exponential.  Try using [ulong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t98873t4.aspx) (max value 2^64 = 18,446,744,073,709,551,615) instead of int (max value 2^31 = 2,147,483,647) - `ulong p = 1` - that should get you a bit further.

If you need to go even further, .NET 4 and up has [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), which can store arbitrarily large numbers.

Comment: @user169654 yeah, as codesparkle noted in the comments, BigInteger is probably the way to go.  You have to add a reference to `System.Numerics` in your project.

Comment: +1... Also interesting fact about factorial that it will start returing 0 due to 2^32 portion of the product.

Answer (score 3):

You are getting 0 because of the way integer overflow handled in most programming languages. You can easily see what happens if you output results of each computation in a loop (using HEX representation):

```
int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
int factorial = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
  factorial *= i;
  Console.WriteLine("{0:x}", factorial);
}
Console.WriteLine(factorial);
```

For n = 34 result look like:

1
2
6
18
78
2d0
13b0
...
2c000000
80000000
80000000
0

Basically multiplying by 2 shifts numbers left and when you multiplied numberer containing enough twos all significant digits will fall out of integer which is 32 bits wide (i.e. first 6 numbers give you 4 twos : 1, 2, 3, 2*2, 5, 2*3, so result of multipying them is 0x2d0 with 4 zero bits at the end).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .net 4.0 and want to calculate factorial of 1000, then try to use `BigInteger` instead of Int32 or Int64 or even UInt64. Your problem statement "doesn't work" is not quite sufficient for me to give some good subjection.
Your code will look something like:

```
using System;
using System.Numerics;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            int factorial = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            var result = CalculateFactorial(factorial);

            Console.WriteLine(result);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static BigInteger CalculateFactorial(int value)
        {
            BigInteger result = new BigInteger(1);
            for (int i = 1; i <= value; i++)
            {
                result *= i;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: " BigInteger "not definition in Code and Compiler give me error!

Comment: I've changed it to full Console Application Snnipet

Comment: i am beginner .sorry(: complier  give error. "numerics" not exist in the spacename

Comment: it should be System.Numerics namespace. Check it once again. In example above this namespace is spelled correctly. I've run that code on my machine and it produced correct results