# Calculating Factorials in C# - No Errors, But Doesn't Work?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I have a simple program that is supposed to calculate the factorial of an entered number. It says I have no errors, but when I run the program it stalls and does not work. Can someone please tell me why?

```
    private void getFactorial_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int userNumber, numberFactorial = 1;

        userNumber = int.Parse(numberInput.Text);
        if (userNumber <= 0)
        {
            numberOutput.Text = numberFactorial.ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 1; 1 <= userNumber; i++)
            {
                numberFactorial = numberFactorial * i;
                numberOutput.Text = numberFactorial.ToString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: What value are you providing for input?

Comment: it works now dreamlax. I had typed "1" where I needed to use "i" in my for loop. That was the issue. Thanks for the reply though

Comment: Side note: before you ask next one on this topic (like "why I get bad answer for 35") please check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13222207/why-computing-factorial-of-realtively-small-numbers-34-returns-0/13222515#13222515

Comment: debug well before posting such a question....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's always the simple things that get us.

In your loop you have this:

```
for (int i = 1; 1 <= userNumber; i++)
```

I believe you mean this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= userNumber; i++)
```

In the conditional part of the loop you used a '1' rather than 'i'.

Comment: Yes. Thank you very much. That was the problem

Answer (score 3):

Your conditional is off for your `for` loop. I think you want `i <= userNumber`.

```
for (int i = 1; i <= userNumber; i++)
```

Comment: Ah, YES!! Thank you. I did not catch that frustrating little mistake :) It works now