# Unable to calculate number of combinations due to very large factorial

Tags: c#, algorithm, combinations, factorial

I am trying to calculate the number of combinations of the number of elements in a certain array. I need the exact number of combinations to use it as number of threads to be executed in the GPU.

But the data is very big and the factorial can't be calculated for that big a number with any data type.

Is there a way to calculate the number of combinations without having to find the factorial? Or a more efficient way to do so?

It summarizes the problem:

```
int no_of_combinations = combination(500,2);
public static int factorial(int m)
{
        int x = 1;

        for (int i = m; i > 0; i--)
            x = x * i;

        return x;
}
public static int combination(int m, int n)
{
    int x = 0;
    x = factorial(m) / (factorial(n) * factorial(m - n));
    return x;
}
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which formula and what is "very big" ? Btw, there is a dedicated site for all math-related questions: [http://math.stackexchange.com/](http://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I am not sure if this is going to help but have you looked up Stirling's approximation? It is an approximation of factorials.

Comment: if you cant even represent the number with a known data type, how are you going to make the same amount of threads?

Comment: @HansP, he is using factorial in formula. Number of threads (result of formula) might be ok (reasonable).

Comment: I'd recommend simplifying the equation beforehand, instead of trying to evaluate 500!, see if you can simplify the fraction

Comment: @Sinatr typically, the number of elements is in hundreds. as things are right now, i can't calculate the factorial of even "100".

Comment: From comment your question is more like duplicate of [Calculate factorials in C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186357/calculate-factorials-in-c-sharp)

Comment: @RyanFitzpatrick YOU ARE A GENIUS!!!! thanks a lot :)

Comment: @AbdulRehman Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In this case I would start to simplify the equation. In your example you're looking for *500 choose 2*, which is 500!/498!/2!. This can be easily changed to 500*499/2, which can be calculated.

In general terms if you have *n choose k*, you only need to calculate a "partial factorial" from *n* to *max(k, n-k)* and then divide by *min(k, n-k)!* due to the results being mirrored. This makes the calculation much easier.

Also in certain cases you could start dividing with the *min(k, n-k)!* while multiplying, but that will lead to remainders etc.

Comment: Actually this is also a valid approach, better to go with the prime divisors though, using Lagendre's formula: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula

Comment: @BorisStrandjev: In what sense is that better? What's the running time, for example?

Comment: @DouglasZare you can afford calculating a lot huger numbers in the approach I propose without fearing overflow. The runnign time for a single combination will be slower, as you need the eratosthenes sieve precalculation, but for multiple calculations it will be faster.

Comment: What is the running time, and how much space does it take? To say it is better than the approach I gave, you should at least match running time that is linear in min(n-k,k) or constant space. It looks to me like it is both slower (in practice and theory) and takes more space, even if you allow a lot of precomputation. Here is an implementation in Lolcode: http://thenerdiestshirts.ecrater.com/p/12755673/programming-t-shirt-size-l-unisex-white. How much code does it take to use Legendre's formula, and what is the chance someone asking the original question will implement it correctly?

Answer (score 3):

Use the Pascal's triangle property:

C(n,k) = C(n - 1, k) + C(n - 1, k - 1) and dynamic programming. No factorials involved.

The triangle of Pascal being:

> ```
>         1
>       1   1
>     1   2   1
>   1   3   3   1
> 1   4   6   4   1
> ```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use factorials. If k>n/2, then use C(n,k)=C(n,n-k). Then use that C(n,0)=1 and for k>0, C(n,k) = C(n,k-1) * (n-k+1)/k. This lets you compute almost as many binomial coefficients as the dynamic programming method but it takes linear time (Theta(min(n-k,k))) and constant space instead of quadratic time and linear space.

See this past question: [How to efficiently calculate a row in pascal's triangle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15580291/how-to-efficiently-calculate-a-row-in-pascals-triangle)

```
public static long combination(int n, int k)
{
  if (n-k < k)
    return combination(n,n-k);
  if (k < 0)
    return 0;
  long result = 1;
  for (int i=1; i<=k; i++)
  {
    result *= n-i+1;
    result /=i;
  } 
  return result;
}
```

This may overflow if the answer times n exceeds the maximum long. So, if you expect the answer to fit in a 32 bit int and you have 64 bit longs, then this should not overflow. To avoid overflowing, use BigIntegers instead of longs.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a new function, lets call it FactorialMoverN

```
int FactorialMOverN(int m, int n)
{
    int x = 1;
        for (int i = m; i > n; i--)
            x = x * i;
    return x;
}
```

Then change your combination function to

```
x = FactorialMOverN(m,n) * factorial(m - n));
```

This should help.  If it doesn't help, then you need to use a different variable type, or rethink your problem.

Thanks to Sami, I can see that the above function is in error.  The 500 choose 2 needs to be calculated via

```
int MChooseN(int m, int n)
    {
        int x = 1;
            for (int i = m; i > (m-n); i--)
                x = x * i;
        return x;
    }
```

The above will take 500, 2 and return 500*499, the previous would have taken 500,2 and returned 500*499*498...5*4*3 which is not what you wanted.

Anyway, the above is the best you can get.

Comment: This will not help in the case when it's for example 500 choose 498. Adding a simple min/max will fix that.

Comment: Yeah, I was confused because I only looked at his code, not at the actual question he was asking.  +1 to you.

Comment: Make it into `i = m; j > max(n, m-n)` type and it will work the same for both 500,2 and 500,498, which have the same result.